# Apply security rule to all EJBs

Tags: security, jboss, ejb, java-ee-6, ejb-3.1

I'm using JBoss AS 7, and I want to apply a role required for all methods of all my EJBs. There is a way to do it in XML ?

I've seen method-permission definition, but in this case I have to define for all ejbs, one by one. As far as I seen, ejb-name element in method-permission does not allow wildcards.

Thanks in advance.